# IIS Update An Application Performance First Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, entity-framework, iis

I have a ecommerce site with ASP.NET MVC and EF6. My site is opening very slow when i update my site for first request. Becuase entity framework's warm up time is high. My site return to normal performance about 10 minutes later.

Is there any suggestion to update my site without any interrupt? May be should i create a new domain called as park.mysite.com and i update it firstly. After that i can change park.mysite.com 's name mysite.com

Is there any optimum solution or what's your opinion.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it doesn't solve the first request performance, just hides it.  The site still needs a request to load all the framework and DLLs by design of IIS.

Comment: i've found like this https://kevinareed.com/2015/11/07/how-to-deploy-anything-in-iis-with-zero-downtime-on-a-single-server/

Comment: Yes, a server farm / load balanced array of servers would solve this, and usually you wouldn't deploy something in production without some redundancy.  You take one server out of the pool, update it, make the first request to spin it up, put it back in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

If problem exactly in cold start after UPDATING you app on a hosting machine, then you need to think about clusterization scenario. Update only part of cluster, while load-balancer/orchestrator will redirect your clients to still available endpoints. Then update the rest of them.

If you was ok with 1 server, then 2 instances will be also enough.

You still need to think about DB part, because in some cases updating of application can require updating of db (for example applying migrations for CF approach), and in such scenario you also have to clasterise db.